# Is it possible to unrar a split RAR archive while simultaneously erasing the compressed version of each part?

Tags: winrar

I am interested in storing some very large mts video files (roughly 3+ GB each) and lets say it takes up about 100 GB. I will compress the entire collection into parts that fit onto a given set of DVD's to be burned for safe keeping. However, once such files are stored, the collection will occupy 100 GB in compressed form, and to decompress them I will have on my drive both the compressed version and the unzipped version (using winRAR for example). But what if the desired location to unzip these files does not have 200 GB of free storage space? Will it be possible to uncompress each part file, say each one is 4.7 GB, and in the end have all the data connected to individual ~3 GB mts video files? Or do all of them need to be uncompressed simultaneously?

Comment: Not sure for 100 but the archive integrity checked on each iteration so this is impossible

Comment: Without the archive index in the previous compressed volumes being accessible, WinRAR won't let you extract succeeding volumes. So I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I would not mind any alternative suggestions either, I might have to seperate each collection of parts to fit a particular number of dvds.

Comment: Your best option might be to not create split archives and instead simply use any good backup program that can compress data and split across DVDs. Such a program should be able to restore without requiring all the parts to exist on the HDD first (i.e. join each successive part to the ones already joined on the HDD).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually rather simple, once I have enough time to think about it with a bit of help from karan (thanks karan). If the target location to unzip has less than 200 GB free space and the collection is 100 GB then the solution may be to make two different libraries of the 100 GB collection, say two 50 GB libraries, and this may or may not result in better disc usage depending on how you break up the collection into separate libraries.